# download as csv not downloading all the axis in high chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export-to-csv, bubble-chart

I have a bubble chart,created in high chart. with three dimension. x-Axis , yAxis and zAxis(size of bubble) 
when I am downloading the data its just giving me first circle xAxis and all other circle yAxis and zAxis.

here is the sample data i downlaoded from my chart.

"Customers","Cluster1 (y)","Cluster1 (z)","Cluster2 (y)","Cluster2 (z)","Cluster3 (y)","Cluster3 (z)","Cluster4 (y)","Cluster4 (z)","Cluster5 (y)","Cluster5 (z)"
45862,318792,387800266.34,703745,871371062.85,583477,692838024.64,542593,622045658.16,268884,310604634.66

[image]

any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: What are you using to download the data from your chart to CSV? Is it the Export-CSV plugin? http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data

Comment: yes i am using the same

Comment: Please ensure that you have the newest Highchart and exporting module. I replicated simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t1tL0xmj/ and seems work fine.

Comment: In the demo you used on series. In my case I have more than 1 series. and same situation.. so in that case its not giving result for all the series